# SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Making a chat application referencing via Node in action, and upon running  the server.js, got the following error: 
    function serveStatic(response,cache,absPath)
    ^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
        at bootstrap_node.js:533:3

Here is the Server.js code:

```
var http=require('http');                             
var fs=require('fs');                                 
var path=require('path');                                                
var path= require('mime');                            
var cache={}; 




var server=http.createServer(function(request,response)
{
    var filePath=false;
    if(request.url=='/')
    {
      filePath= public/index.html;
    }
    else
    {
      'public' + request.url;
    }

    var absPath= './'+filePath;
    serveStatic(response,cache,absPath);
});

server.listen(3000,function() 
{

 console.log('Server listening to the port :3000');

});




function send404 (response )
{
    response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type' :'text/plain'});
    response.write('Error 404: resource not found');
    response.end();
}




function sendFile(response,filePath,fileContents)
{
    response.wrieHead(200,
       {"content-type":mime.lookup(filePath)})

       };
       response.end(fileContents);

}



function serveStatic(response,cache,absPath)
{
    if(cache[absPath])
    {
    sendFile(response,absPath,cache[absPath]);
    }
    else
    {
       if(fs.exists(absPath, function(exists)))
       {
        if(exists)
        {
          fs.readFile(absPath,function(err,data))
          {
          if(err)

          {
            send404(response);
          }
          else
          {
            cache[absPath]=data;
            sendFile(response,absPath,data);
          }
          });

        }
        else
        {
        send404(response);
        }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: `filePath= public/index.html;`  is missing quotes and `'public' + request.url;` is a no-op that does nothing ...

Comment: @AlexK. , got these missing quotes at the place now, still the same error as shown above

Comment: you seem to have a few extra random `}` and a random `)` as well - indent your code properly to see the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yeah having little extra braces ,  correct it out now and working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra brackets here:

```
function sendFile(response,filePath,fileContents)
{
    response.wrieHead(200,
       {"content-type":mime.lookup(filePath)})

       };
       response.end(fileContents);

}
```

Should be modified this way:

```
function sendFile(response, filePath, fileContents)
{
    response.wrieHead(200, {
      "content-type": mime.lookup(filePath)
    });
    response.end(fileContents);

}
```

Then your error will be dismissed.

Comment: Thank you , It helps , although apart from this, there were also few other syntax errors, running is fine now and Server listening to the port :3000 :)